# Firebase Libraries/Dependencies Issue

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Because Google is dropping support for Google Cloud Messaging (The Mother of all Breaking Changes),I'm forced to convert my wonderful messaging app to firebase messaging.

The good news is that there are a number of tutorials and samples to aid in this conversion.

The bad news is that they all say something different.

[This link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) tells us that all we have to put into our dependencies section in our app-level build.gradle is

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0"
```

However the simple sample chat app wont run without

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

also included and I haven't been able to find out yet what that library is for.

[these offical docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) tells me to include

```
compile 'com.firebaseeui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
```

whatever that is.

[These "offical docs"](http://These) attempt to document gradle dependencies by service but they don't even mention those last two dependencies.

It's a mess.  These are just a couple of examples - I could make this post much longer.

Is there any place that defines ALL the firebase dependencies and what they are for?

Comment: `com.firebase` libraries are deprecated. The Firebase UI github pages specifically say which versions of Firebase Database are supported

Comment: cricket_007: "Firebase UI github" is where I'm supposed to look?  I've been looking at firebase.google.com/docs for documentation.  Is that somehow the wrong place to look?

Comment: FirebaseUI is a separate project... https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Answer (score 2):

It's listed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

> Gradle Dependency Line    Service
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2  Analytics
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0  Realtime Database
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0 Cloud Firestore
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2   Storage
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2 Crash Reporting
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0  Authentication
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2 Cloud Messaging
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2    Remote Config
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:15.0.1   Invites and Dynamic Links
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0   AdMob
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0   App Indexing
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.2.0  Performance Monitoring
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0 Cloud Functions for Firebase Client SDK
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:15.0.0 ML Kit (Vision)
>
> com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-tensorflow:15.0.0 ML Kit (Custom Model)

For FCM, what you only need for it to function is:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

And if you want to be able to take advantage of the additional analytics feature tied to FCM, you could add `com.google.firebase:firebase-core`.

Your official docs link is broken, so I'm not sure what docs you're pointing out. But AFAIK, you could just follow the [official setup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) and you should be fine. Migration from GCM to FCM shouldn't be that much of a problem.

Comment: AL you might want to give my post another read.  The docs say what you say.  the point of my post is the docs don't match the Google tutorials and samples and the samples won't run with what you say is needed.  It's a mess.

Comment: Hey Dean. I'm pretty sure I got that part. What I'm trying to point out here is focus on the main documentation. If you keep on switching between different tutorials, you'll definitely end with a messy project. I have multiple apps that use FCM, and whenever I start implementing them, I just follow the official start up guide. And everything works fine. If you could edit your post to specify what the actual error is, I'll try to cater my answer to it, coz right now, the thing that sticks out the most is "*Is there any place that defines ALL the firebase dependencies and what they are for?*"